# Flutter: Change Statusbar Text Color not working properly

Tags: flutter, statusbar, flutter-theme, flutter-design

Almost all the Q/A referred on Stackoverflow related to the same topic but didn't get proper solutions.

Main Question: My app having the primary color **blue** and I want to set **Statusbar Text Color** white.

What I have tried:

- Using **SystemChrome:** (Using the following code, It's just changing the color of **status bar text** in the first screen only, other screens are having blue/black combination background/foreground.)

  ```
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: MaterialColor(0xFF084775, color), // status bar color
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,//status bar brightness
      statusBarIconBrightness:Brightness.light , //status barIcon Brightness
  ));
  ```

**Screenshots:**

Splash Screen:

[image]

Dashboard Screen:

[image]

---

- Using **ThemeData** : (This method gives the same result as the above screenshot).

  ```
   theme: ThemeData(
              brightness: Brightness.light, // ADDED THIS LINE..
              primarySwatch: MaterialColor(0xFF084775, color),
              accentColor: Color(0xffe46b10),
              unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey,
              fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
            ),
  ```

I have also checked **[github issue link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16740)** but not worked for me.

I just need to change Statusbar Text Color to White. Any help?

Comment: You should try to add Brightness parameter in Appbar this might works.

Comment: For which appBar, I have 25 screen and all the screens have AppBar

Comment: You should define appBar theme also. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To apply for all appBar use

```
 return MaterialApp(
                theme: ThemeData(
                  appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(brightness: Brightness.dark),
                ),
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                // home: InvoiceList(),
                home: widget());
```

I hope it will works.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much:) It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As of Flutter 2

```
return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
            appBarTheme: Theme.of(context)
                .appBarTheme
                .copyWith(systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light)),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: widget());
```